# Kendo MVC grid group by footer template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC grid with 3 columns Country, State and Sales columns. I turned on grouping and footer total for Sales column. Footer total is displaying sales amount fine.

My requirement is that when grouped by Country, I need to display "Country Total: SUM" in group footer and when grouped by State, I need to display "State Total: SUM".

How can I display column name in client footer template based on the column grouped?

Here is my code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<InvoiceApprovalWorkflow.ViewModels.RegionSalesViewModel>()
    .Name("SalesAmount")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 200px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("BatchDetails_GetSales", "Sales", new { id = ViewBag.BatchID }))
         .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.TotalUSD).Sum();
        })
    )
        .Sortable()
        .Groupable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).ClientFooterTemplate("Total:").Width("300px").ClientGroupFooterTemplate("Total");
        columns.Bound(c => c.State).ClientFooterTemplate("Total:").Width("300px").ClientGroupFooterTemplate("Total");
        columns.Bound(c => c.TotalUSD).Format("{0:c0}").ClientFooterTemplate("#= kendo.format('{0:c0}', sum)#")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: right" });
    })
    )
```

Comment: How does a column get grouped? So you can go back and forth between grouping by Country and State?

Comment: Updated code, i have grouping() enabled on both country and state columns, users can drag and drop column onto the group header back and forth on the fly